# Solving a linear homogeneous second-order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I'd like to solve a PDE of the form
$$
\frac{\partial^2 z(x,y)}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(g(x)\frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)
$$
where $g$ is known and $z$ is the funciton to be solved for. This looks like a modified version of the wave equation; if $g$ were a constant it would reduce to the wave equation. It's linear and homogeneous, so it has some nice properties, but I've yet to find a method to solve it analytically.

A back-up option is to use separation of variables and pursue a series solution. Writing $z(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$,
$$
\frac{1}{Y}\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial y^2} = -\omega^2 = \frac{1}{X}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(g(x)\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}\right) \, .
$$
The $X$ part becomes
$$
0 = g(x)\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial X}{\partial x} + \omega^2 X
$$
which I still do not know yet know how to solve.

Can anyone offer some suggestions for how to attack this problem, or do I appear to be out of luck?

EDIT: I did not specify $g$ because I'm interested in the case where it is any monotonically increasing function - essentially, it's a control parameter. Although I'd like to keep it general, any case that makes this problem solvable analytically would be still be useful to know. The case $g(x)=ax^2$ for some $a$ yields a Cauchy-Euler ODE which I can solve analytically. I'm not aware of any others.

Comment: What is $g$ ? If you know it, it would make solving this analytically easier.

Comment: The x equation is a Sturm-Liouville equation, so you might look into methods for those.

Comment: In the general case the solution cannot be expressed in terms of a combination of a finite number of standard functions. An answer can be given  only in few particular cases of functions $g(x)$. Please specify what kind of function $g(x)$ is.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect that I'm interested in the general case, but any analytically solvable case where $g(x)$ is monotonically increasing would be helpful.